# Unary-Operators postfix and prefix at the same time in java

Tags: java, prefix, unary-operator, postfix-operator

My question in plain English: why this works `someObject.methodReturnsInteger().getClass()` (I don't really mean the `getClass` method. Just a method that works with Integer. And I don't really mean a method that returns an Integer specifically.) but this doesn't `++a++`?

In other words, why (or how) parsing (or tokenizing) allows using the return value in the first but doesn't in the second? I mean, shouldn't it parse the latter like so: `(++a)++` and use the return of `++a` as a number?

The same goes for something like: `a+++++b`

I hope the question is clear enough.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `++a++` consists of 3 pieces, highlighted by adding parenthesis: `(++(a))++`:

- `a` variables reference
- `++X` Prefix Increment Operator ([JLS §15.15.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1))
- `X++` Postfix Increment Operator ([JLS §15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2))

Javadoc says:

> **[X] must be a variable** of a type that is convertible ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to a numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs. [...] **The result** of the [prefix/postfix] increment expression **is not a variable, but a value**.

So, in your expression `++a` works, because `a` is a variable, but the result is a *value*, so `(++a)++` doesn't work.

---

`a+++++b` doesn't work because it is parsed by the compiler as `((a++)++)+b`, and as we just learned, `X++` needs a variable.

It is parsed this way because the Java tokenizer will consume as many consecutive characters as possible to form a valid operator.

Now, if you add spaces or parenthesis, it can work, depending of what you intended that expression to do. The following are all the same:

```
(a++)+(++b)
a+++(++b)
a++ + ++b
a+++ ++b
```

---

The expression `someObject.methodReturnsInteger().getClass()` is known as "[method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)".

This works because `.` is a left-associative [method invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) operator, and the value to the left of the `.` just has to be an object (or class for static method call, but let's skip that).

So the expression is parsed like this:
`( someObject . methodReturnsInteger() ) . getClass()`

The first `.` works because `someObject` is an object. The second `.` works because the result of the parenthesized expression is an object.

Method chaining is very common, and is very nice when using a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), e.g.

```
String s = new StringBuilder()
        .append("Hello ")
        .append(person.getFirstName())
        .append(", please say hello to your father, ")
        .append(person.getFather().getFirstName())
        .append(".")
        .toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator doesn't work on numbers, it works on variables. `x++` is allowed because `x` is a variable. Something like `++(x++)` isn't allowed because the result of `(x++)` is a number not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Operations that *store* a value need a place to put it.   You can't say `(a*2)++`, because the expression `(a*2)` returns a temporary result.  Incrementing it would have no effect, because that temporary result is immediately discarded.  For the same reason, you can't say `(a*2)=10`.

It might make a little more sense to say `++(a*2)`, but that still indicates that you want to store the incremented value when you don't have a valid place to put it, so the language designers would rather you write `(a*2)+1` instead.

The post-fix and pre-fix increment operators *also* return temporary results, which is why you can't apply them twice or in combination.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Before being converted to an `Integer` reference, it was an `int` -- a 32-bit integer quantity.  This is a primitive type that is not an `Object`.  Java automatically converts `int`s to and from `Integer` objects in many cases, mostly to make generic classes work better.  See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Ah, true. I didn't try it without some other kind of implicit cast.  I'll remove that part of the answer